# Youtube embeds: is transparent background possible? .ytp-transparent

Tags: css, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am having trouble with youtube embeds. I am trying to fix this
[border radius: background bleed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpAha.png)

I have crawled the DOM of the iframe, it seems that, for example, changing the background to white  could solve issue.

//CSS
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/s/player/9216d1f7/www-player-webp.css

//LINE 20:
html5-video-player:not(.ytp-transparent), .html5-video-player.unstarted-mode, .html5-video-player.ad-showing, .html5-video-player.ended-mode, .html5-video-player.ytp-fullscreen { background-color: #000; }

I found no option to set .ytp-transparent
Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.